How to adjust the increment of copying and pasting in excel cells
I need some help with how I can adjust the increment of excel copying and pasting formulas. Because normally, if u copy and paste formulas, Excel keeps the increment of the Cells - but I have a large table and doing it by hand takes a lot of time.
Excel works like that:
Taking formula
=IF(ISBLANK('Project1'!B2);0;'Project1'!B2)
from C9 and pasting it in C12 gives me
=IF(ISBLANK('Project1'!B5);0;'Project1'!B5)
What I want to do is to take the formula
=IF(ISBLANK('Project1'!B2);0;'Project1'!B2)
from C9 and paste it in C12 to get
=IF(ISBLANK('Project1'!B3);0;'Project1'!B3)
I tried with the indirect and Row functions from this draft, but I can't seem to get it work. Is this behaviour of excel even adjustable?

Try using the following:


=TOCOL(EXPAND(IF(B2:B4="","",B2:B4),,3,""))


Or, without Spill!
=LET(a, INDEX(B$2:B$4,IF(N(MOD(ROW(),3)=0),INT(ROW()/3)-2,"")),
     IFERROR(IF(a="","",a),""))


All of these above formulas don't use any Volatile Functions, therefore no risk of recalculations whenever there is a change in the open workbook, as well not single threaded !



Shorter version of the above:
=IFERROR(INDEX(IF(B$2:B$4="","",B$2:B$4),INT(ROW()/3)-2/N(MOD(ROW(),3)=0)),"")


